# SD card shrinking stuff

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Just going to say that there seem to a lot of questions with 'How do I make a SD card image smaller?' or 'Fit SD card image onto other (smaller) SD' etc:

Shrinking Image

- [Truncating SD image](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31805/truncating-sd-image)
- [How to shrink an image file after allocating full space](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36456/how-to-shrink-an-image-file-after-allocating-full-space)
- [Image of a 16Gb card containing unpartitioned space at the end: Truncating possible?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7177/image-of-a-16gb-card-containing-unpartitioned-space-at-the-end-truncating-possi) (very similar to method I use, which I know works....)

Both:

- [Use smaller space when i have expand it?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8437/use-smaller-space-when-i-have-expand-it)
- [SD Image won't fit on SD Card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15796/sd-image-wont-fit-on-sd-card)

Smaller SD:

- [Copy existing Raspbian installation to smaller SD card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5440/copy-existing-raspbian-installation-to-smaller-sd-card)
- [How to restore Image of SD card from a larger SD card to smaller one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12613/how-to-restore-image-of-sd-card-from-a-larger-sd-card-to-smaller-one)

I can't make head or tail of whether any of them should be duplicates... would it be a good idea to edit/add new clearer answers? Also there are probably lots more questions I didn't find...

Comment: Yeah, this is quite a tangle.   Part of the problem is I think there's distinctly different possibilities for linux, OSX, and windows.  It would be good to get opinions here about which ones people consider the most useful for various platforms.  I'm a bad judge because the way I do this kind of thing would probably not be considered "user friendly".

Comment: Same here :) The scripts seem a good idea but have a few flaws - also many solutions will need linux, as the tools may not be available under Windows/Mac conventionally (some are via cygwin, and Mac will likely have equivalents to some commands)